# Android: Not receiving TIME_TICK broadcast when application is not on top

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have a requirement to be able to monitor my application's state each minute even if the application is not on top.

SO I am using TIME_TICK broadcast for this. However, when the application is not on top, I am not receiving the broadcast. But, when my application is running on top I am getting it.

Any work around for this?

Comment: Where do you register your TIME_TICK receiver?  The `onCreate()` method of an activity?  And you never unregister it?  How soon after your app goes into the background do you stop receiving the broadcasts?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are registering the receiver at your manifest.xml file.

as the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) says:

> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You
>   cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by
>   explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

Comment: I have done exactly what you are recommending. That's why I am able to get Broadcast when my application is running.

Comment: That's not a recommendation, that's a fact, you can't do that. can you be more specific about ehat you want to do?

Comment: I have registered for TIME_TICK broadcast. I am receiing the broadcast when I my application is on top. But, when I am closing my app, I am not able to receive the broadcast, even though I didn't unregister the concerned IntentFilter. I need to receive TIME_TICK broadcast each min. irrespective of my app on top or not.

Answer (score 0):

I tried TIME_TICK in every way possible. The thing with TIME_TICK is that it is only active when the application concerned is up and running. Yes we do have to explicitly register for the broadcast from a Activity. But, even after that though I didn't unregister when exiting from the app, I was not getting the broadcast(Since Activity was dead so mostly the Broadcast registration was gone).

The solution which worked for me in this case is using AlarmManager, by setting a setRepeat alarm for each minute.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that AlarmManager will fire each minute? I am not getting called alarm manager's receiver, it is for app notifications.